# Contact auto-create trigger : name parsing issue

Tags: apex, trigger, case, contact

We have the following Case Trigger, to auto-create a Contact upon case creation:

```
trigger CaseAutocreateContact on Case (before insert) {

  Map<String, Case> suppliedEmailCases = new Map<String, Case>();
  Map<String, Contact> suppliedEmailExistingContacts = new Map<String, Contact>();
  List<Contact> newContacts = new List<Contact>();

  // We should update all the cases where the contact was not given
  // And an Email address was supplied.
    for (Case caseObj:Trigger.new) {
        if (caseObj.ContactId == null &&
            caseObj.SuppliedEmail != '' &&
            caseObj.SuppliedEmail != null){

            // We will update this case in any case, whether
            // the contact is new or old
            suppliedEmailCases.put(caseObj.SuppliedEmail, caseObj);
        }
    }

    // Finding all the contacts that already exist in the DB
    List<Contact> existingContacts = [Select Id,Email,Phone From Contact Where Email in :suppliedEmailCases.keySet()];
    for (Contact c:existingContacts){
      suppliedEmailExistingContacts.put(c.Email, c);
    }

  // Creating new Contacts for the ones that do not exist, and updating information to the ones that did exist
  for(Case caseObj:suppliedEmailCases.values()){
    Contact c = suppliedEmailExistingContacts.get(caseObj.SuppliedEmail);
    if(c == null){
      String firstName = '';
      String lastName =  caseObj.SuppliedEmail; // We use the email if nothing else is available

            // Handle Missing Name by using the Email address instead
            if (caseObj.SuppliedName != null){
              String[] nameParts = caseObj.SuppliedName.split(' ');

              // Last Name is always the last part of the name
            // We take it and remove it
            lastName = nameParts.remove(nameParts.size() - 1);
            if(nameParts.size() > 0){
              // All the other parts of the name are first names
              firstName = String.join(nameParts, ' ');
            }
            }

            newContacts.add(new Contact(FirstName=firstName,
                              LastName=lastName,
                              Email=caseObj.SuppliedEmail,
                              Phone=caseObj.SuppliedPhone,
                              Autocreated__c=true)
                          );
    }
    else {
      if (c.Phone == null || c.Phone == '') {
        c.Phone = caseObj.SuppliedPhone;
        update c;
      }

      // Attach the existing contact to the case
      caseObj.ContactId = c.Id;
    }
  }

  // Now we insert all the new Contacts  
  // Old Contacts were already attached to the Cases
    insert newContacts;

    // And we update the contactId of all the cases with new contacts
    for(Contact c:newContacts){
      Case caseObj = suppliedEmailCases.get(c.Email);
      caseObj.ContactId = c.Id;
    }
}
```

We are facing an issue with the creation of new contacts where the declared name is "Smith, John (john.smith@test.com)".

The parsing erroneously sets the First name as Last, and vise-versa.

[image: Contact Detail]

Comment: Gah, DML in a `for` loop!

Comment: You need to be splitting on the '.' in the name split to do what you're asking. I don't see where you're specifying a split by character or regex, only a space.

Comment: This is an issue which can be resolved by debug only. It is hard to identify what values you are getting and what are the intermediate parsing results into wrong output. On the other side, @AdrianLarson has highlighted something important!

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code you posted that you parse the email address? Am I missing it? All I see is you assigning the suppliedEmail to the lastName field

Comment: Thanks. I just found a similar 'official' SalesForce Developers article ([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Autocreating_Contacts_From_Web_To_Case)), but it seems as though the solution there also doesn't handle splitting on   ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you move your code to a `Service Layer`, an `Apex Class` capable of performing `static` operations on your data. In this case, it would also help you increase separation of concerns.

I would break out the parsing methods, and avoid using `split`. It probably makes your code more complex than it needs to be in this case. Simpler to use `substring methods:

```
public with sharing class CaseService
{
    public static String parseFirstName(Case record)
    {
        if (record.SuppliedEmail == null) return null;
        return record.SuppliedName.contains(', ') ?
            record.SuppliedName.substringAfter(', ') :
            record.SuppliedName.substringBeforeLast(' ');
    }
    public static String parseLastName(Case record)
    {
        if (record.SuppliedEmail == null) return null;
        return record.SuppliedName.contains(', ') ?
            record.SuppliedName.substringBefore(', ') :
            record.SuppliedName.substringAfterLast(' ');
    }
    public static Contact getSuppliedContact(Case record)
    {
        return new Contact(
            Phone = record.SuppliedPhone,
            Email = record.SuppliedEmail,
            FirstName = parseFirstName(record),
            LastName = parseLastName(record)
        );
    }
}
```

You might also consider a bulk save action for the related `Contact` records, and while writing it, you can move your `DML Operation` outside your `for` loop.

```
public static void saveSuppliedContacts(List<Case> records)
{
    Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();
    for (Case record : records) emails.add(record.SuppliedEmail);

    Map<String, Contact> contacts = new Map<String, Contact>();
    for (Contact record : [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :emails])
        contacts.put(record.Email, record);

    for (Case record : records)
    {
        if (!contacts.containsKey(record.SuppliedEmail))
            contacts.put(record.SuppliedEmail, getSuppliedContact(record));
        contacts.get(record.SuppliedEmail).Phone = record.SuppliedPhone;
    }
    upsert contacts.values();
    // error handling strongly recommended but omitted here for brevity
}
```